# How to trigger media Queries in javascript for style.width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries, viewport-units

I'm working on a onclick event (html) with jquery. 
In my jquery i set the width for this event.

Though i want a different width for the mobile website. For this I should work with media queries. 
On desktop it is 50vw, on phone (triggered from 600px) it should be 100vw...
Though how to make this work properly?

```
function openMenu() {
document.getElementById("menuNav").style.width = "50vw"; 
}

function closeMenu() {
    document.getElementById("menuNav").style.width = "0vh";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($(window).width() < 601) { 
    // change functionality for smaller screens
} else { 
    // change functionality for larger screens
}e
```

or

```
if(window.matchMedia('(max-width: 600px)').matches)
{
    // do functionality on screens smaller than 600px
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Define .open class and .closed class in CSS where you can use media queries normally. Then switch CSS classes on `menuNav` with JavaScript. See documentation for classList: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) method to find the width of the window (IE the browser viewport) and determine whether 50vw or 100vw should be used:

```
function openMenu() {
    if($(window).width() > 600) {
        document.getElementById("menuNav").style.width = "50vw";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("menuNav").style.width = "100vw"; 
    }
}
```